# How to disable standard performance counters in Application Insights via JavaScript SDK?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Standard performance counters in Application Insights generate too much volume. How can I disable them and only report my own counters + some standard ones (if needed)? I am using JavaScript SDK for application insights. Hence, expecting a fix related to same.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to disable performance counters for JavaScript SDK since their calculation is done by backends based on ingested telemetry. Can you please elaborate what you're trying to solve by reducing a volume?

Comment: We receive huge amounts of unnecessary data beacuse of standard performance counters and it leads to huge cost. Hence disabling that would help us to display custom data alone.

Comment: This makes sense. I'll look around whether there are options. Do you have a support plan to open a ticket about it? It might be easier to track it and get attention this way (no guarantees that there is a solution). In case you do and open a ticket, please send me a ticket # to (SO alias) _at_ microsoft.

Comment: QQ - can you please give me an example of a standard performance counter which JavaScript SDK generates which you don't need?

Comment: PerformanceCounters are only sent from server components where you have service side ApplicationInsights (eg: Asp.Net, Asp.Net Core) SDK installed. Javascript SDK won't end performance counters.